# Is there any flutter upgrade / update without problems?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, upgrade, flutter-dependencies

can anybody tell if there is a way to upgrade to the newest sdk flutter version and all pub devs without facing compile problems with the existing app.
It's so frustrating with these upgrades.

What is the best solution to upgrade and what exactly should be updated?

The sdk, all dependencies, only some dependencies, android studio,or everything at once if there's a newer version?

What is the best solution in a normal flutter developer day? Thanks

Comment: Many people have upgraded with no problems.  Some people have problems because they changed to 2.12 in their pubspec, without running dart migrate to do it for them (and fix most of everything else).  Some run into trouble because they depend on pub packages that haven't made the 2.12 leap yet (run dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety first!).